# Add column in sales order grid table in magento2

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I have added two columns in sales order grid table. But only one value is showing in that two column i don't know how to return multiple values in column, below code is `prepareDataSource` function inside that UI folder.

```
   public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
            $school_name = $order->getData('school_name');
            $seller_id = $order->getData('seller_id');
            if(empty($school_name))
            {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = 'Default';
            }
            else
            {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $school_name;
            }
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

I want to return that `$seller_id` please tell me how to return.